# Angular Installation: npm warn deprecated /module angular can not find

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

Could someone help me with this problem:

1. i install "npm install -g @angular/cli" on my computer
2. them i go to git to clone the documents to a repository called 'frontend'
3. i open the CMD in the 'frontend' folder and try to run 'ng serve'(node have been already installed)

And now in the cmd line:

```
npm warn deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated.....etc
...
can not find module'@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
```

How can i make this work?

PS, since i already installed:node/angular so i do not need to run 'npm install' inside folder before 'ng serve' is that right?

Comment: you always need to run `npm install` in the folder of the project, because that installs dependencies for that specific project, which may not only be angular, but a whole bunch of other stuff. Plus when you install angular globally you only install CLI which allows you to run commands, but all other angular packages have to be installed in the project.

Comment: Can somebody conclude the steps of installing here? These are not listed in official docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install @angular-devkit/build-angular as dev dependency. This package is newly introduced in Angular 6.0

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: Thanks for your answer,    apparently it came from the errors of installations, so i reinstall the angular/cli and it works , but the warning of 'warn deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated....." are still there when i run npm!.